# In TFS, is there a maximum amount of workspaces which can be used for a user?

Tags: .net, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm currently in the process of creating a bunch of new build scripts for our platform. Things went okay until I encountered the following error:

```
D:\TFS\WorkingDir\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(173,5): error MSB4018: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WorkspaceNotFoundException: TF14061: The workspace BUILDMACHINENAME_9;BUILDMACHINENAME\TFSService does not exist.
```

When I take a look at the list of workspaces (with Team Foundation Sidekicks) I see there are a bunch of BUILDMACHINENAME_xxx workspaces, where xxx is a number ranging from 1 to 8.

What I'm thinking is that TFS reaches some kind of limit (10 probably) of the amount of workspaces it can create for a certain owner, and thus fails to create a workspace for the build automatically.

Can this be the case?

Anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still clueless about what caused this problem and how to properly resolved this, but I got it to work by using the following workaround:

I created a new workspace with the required name by using the tf.exe command line utility:

```
tf workspace /new /computer:BUILDMACHINE BUILDMACHINE_9;TFSService
```

This brings up a dialog window where the working folders can be set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such limit.  If it exists, it's *much* higher than 10.

My guess is that you modified the `<IncrementalGet>` property in your build script and/or stopped the build process in the middle of something.  When this MSBuild property is false, Team Build deletes & recreates a new workspace during every build.  When it's true, Team Build expects the workspace to already exist so it can simply run "Get Latest".